# form-data request, with okHttp3

Tags: java, http, okhttp, java-ee-6

I'm trying to make a request where I pass some parameters in the Body, as shown in the image.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVcAr.png)

Example:

`Key: file[], Value: "xml",  Content-Type: application/xml Key: query,  Value: {"boxe/File": false},  Content-Type: application/xml`

I'm getting a *Bad Request* error, I think my code isn't right. Follow how it is being done

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("file[]", xml, RequestBody.create(null, "application/xml"))
        .addFormDataPart("query", "{\"boxe/File\": false}", RequestBody.create(null, "application/xml"))
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(endPoint).addHeader("x-integration-key", integrationKey)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        .post(requestBody).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it, the order of the parameters were wrong,

follow the correct order

```
  RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file[]","", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/xml"), xml))
            .addFormDataPart("query", "", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), boxFileJson))
            .build();
```